# Quitar 0's de la matriz y añadir 1's , luego hacer una matriz circular

Tags: python

Estoy intentando hacer una matriz circular , primero he creado una matriz de ceros y sustituirlos por unos , y luego quiero hacer esta matriz de manera circular , es decir , que los 1's estén de manera circular. Pero no sé que propiedades debe la matriz para hacerlo de esta manera. También me da error el código que he intentado, intentando meter unos en la matriz

```
def circleMask(rad):
    mask = np.zeros((rad*2,rad*2),np.uint8) #devuelve matriz de 0's
    print(mask)
    for i in mask:
        for j in mask[i]:
            mask[i,j]=  1

    return mask

print(circleMask(2))
```

Ejemplo de salida esperada:

```
[[0 0 1 0 0],
 [1 1 1 1 1],
 [1 1 1 1 1],
 [1 1 1 1 1],
 [0 0 1 0 0]]
```

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar un ejemplo del resultado esperado?

Comment: [[0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0]]

Comment: Realmente no estoy seguro a lo que se refiee con una matriz circular ( máscara)

Comment: Entiendo que es algo como esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865023/circular-masking-an-image-in-python-using-numpy-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

desde mi punto de vista el **número de celdas de la array 2D** (es decir, el diámetro) 
será **radius*2 + 1**. De esa manera conseguimos una matriz simétrica donde poder dibujar un circulo justo en el centro. Por ejemplo, si hacemos circleMask(2), tendremos 
una array de 5x5. Si además queremos asegurar una mejor visión del circulo de 1's dentro de la matriz, entonces yo **añadiría un pequeño offset**, siempre en número par, por ejemplo un offset de dos daría una matriz de 7x7.

A continuación, lo que tenemos que hacer es **poblar matriz en función de la formula del circulo r2 = x2 + y2** centrado en 0,0. Donde r = radius.(Veremos que esto requiere una traslación posterior al sistema de indexado de la array en numpy).

Por lo tanto, **si hacemos un barrido en x**, asignado valores enteros a x dentro del rango determinado por [-radius,radius] (incluyendo el cero claro) podemos determinar que valor debe tomar y para cada x dado.
En nuestro caso tendremos un rango definido por [-2,2], lo que se traduce en una lista de **valores para x igual a [-2,1,0,1,2]**, dados estos valores calculamos los valores de cada y los cuales serán **y = [±0.0,±1.73,±2.0,±1.73,±0.0]**.

Para trasladar las listas X e Y obtenidas al sistema de indexado del array en numpy, simplemente sumamos a cada valor de la lista x la coordenada x del centro de dicho array. Así, obtenemos la lista de las coordenadas X modificada y lista para ser usadas por la función pinta que poblará la array creada previamente.

**Una solución** a esto puede ser el siguiente código:

```
import numpy as np
import math

# necesitamos una funcion que pinte (rellene de 1's las posiciones de la matriz)
# array es la array 2D que debemos rellenar de 1's segÃºn la figura de un circulo
def pinta(array,listaCoordenadasX,listaCantidadDeCeldasYAPintar): 

    centerY = int((len(array)-1)/2)

    for x,cantidadCeldasYAPintar in zip(listaCoordenadasX,listaCantidadDeCeldasYAPintar):
        r = range(0,int(cantidadCeldasYAPintar) + 1,1)
        for celda in r:
            #por lo de +- de la solucion
            array[centerY+celda][x] = 1
            array[centerY-celda][x] = 1


def circleMask(rad,radOffset):

    #pasamos el radio a entero
    radAsInt =int(round(float(rad),1))
    #damos un offset al radio para ver bien el circulo en la array bidimensional
    radOffsetAsInt =int(round(float(radOffset),1))
    #obtenemos el centro de la matriz (en X. En Y es igual, pero aqui no lo necesitamos)
    centerX = radAsInt + radOffsetAsInt   

    # En base a lo anterior calculamos el diametro del circulo
    # hacemos el diametro del circulo un numero impar para conseguir simetria
    # con respecto asl centro de la matriz
    d = radAsInt*2+1
    dOffset = radOffsetAsInt*2

    #devuelve matriz de 0's
    mask = np.zeros((d+dOffset,d+dOffset),np.uint8) 

    #En este for calculamos, haciendo un barrido en x el valor que debe tomar y.
    #Todo en base a la formula de un circulo (radAsInt+0.5)**2 = x**2 + y**2 centrado en 0,0
    #El valor de +-y se interpreta como la cantidad de celdas de la matriz que deben ser pintadas para
    #cada valor de x.

    listaCoordenadasX = list()
    listaCantidadDeCeldasAPintar = list()

    #rango para la obtencion de las x para el barrido
    r = range(-(radAsInt),(radAsInt)+1,1)

    for x in r:

        #y = +-math.sqrt((radAsInt+0.5)**2 - x**2 + y**2)
        y = math.sqrt(((radAsInt)**2)-(x**2))
        #correccion del centro en X a nuestro sistema matricial 
        xbis = centerX+x
        listaCoordenadasX.append(xbis)
        listaCantidadDeCeldasAPintar.append(y)

    #poblamos la array 2D para cada valor de xbis con el valor de y obtenido
    pinta(mask,listaCoordenadasX,listaCantidadDeCeldasAPintar)


    return mask
```

Para testearlo podemos ejecutar el siguiente:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    #test1
    radius = 0
    radiusOffset = 2
    print(circleMask(radius,radiusOffset))

    #test2        
    radius = 1
    radiusOffset = 2
    print(circleMask(radius,radiusOffset))

    #test3
    radius = 2
    radiusOffset = 2
    print(circleMask(radius,radiusOffset))

    #test4
    radius = 6
    radiusOffset = 2
    print(circleMask(radius,radiusOffset))
```

Y los resultados:

```
#test1

[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]

#test2

[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

#test3

[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

#test4

[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```